# C#, Listbox Horizontal Alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a WPF app and I want to add an item with HorizontalAlignment = Left and then other with HorizontalAlignment = right, like a chat in Whatsapp, but all the text in the listbox have horizontal alignment on the right, How can I use different horizontal alignment in the same listbox.

This is my XAML code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxChat" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="366"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Margin="2,44,0,0" Padding="2"/>
 <TextBlock Foreground="Transparent" Name="TextB" Margin="2,-5,2,-3"></TextBlock>
```

and this is the C# code behind:

```
ListBoxChat.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
ListBoxChat.Items.Add("How are you ?");

ListBoxChat.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
ListBoxChat.Items.Add("Fine!!!");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Easiest way: You should add a new textbox for each message and set its HorizontalAlignment property and put them in a stackpanel

Comment: you don't `ListBox.Items.Add()` in WPF. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single `StackPanel` to carry the `ListView`. Like this,

```
<StackPanel>
  <ListView x:Name="chatList" Width="value" />
</StackPanel>
```

You don't really need the StackPanel, I *just* used it!

Now on the CSharp code, you can handle the events of the User or the Network. I won't go in the Depth of the process, but an example of that would be

```
void addItem (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // first create the new item!
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    // add the properties..
    item.Content = "Hi, my name is Slim Shady!";
    if(messageBy == "user") {
        // if message is by user, align it to right
        item.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    } else {
        // if message is by network (friend), align it to left
        item.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    }
    // now add the item to the listbox
    chatList.Items.Add(item); // done! :-)
}
```

You can execute this code, each time there is new item to be appened! But you really need to make sure that the conditions are checked. Because using the Condition, you can change the color of the item too, like in *WhatsApp*, you can do other stuff too. It totally depends on the Condition, and the Way you use it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by applying the style on your `ListBoxItem` and using `AlternationCount` and `AlternationIndex` as shown below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxChat" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="366"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Margin="2,44,0,0" Padding="2"
        AlternationCount="2">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
             </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: @user3745396 while working with wpf, one should learn mvvm first and something that can be done in xaml only, should get the preference over code